# How to create select input field like HTML select input using Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am still new in flutter and I want to create like HTML select field with `value` and `text`.
For example:
I have these data `doctors = [{'id':1,'name':'Jolly'},{'id':2,'Mat'}]`
I want to create select input field for this kind of data, when I select a doctor I need to get the doctor's id from the select.
How can I do this using Flutter.

Answer (score 0):

basic implementation to select one doc at a time

```
class DoctorData(){
DoctorData({this.name,this.id})
final String? name;
final int? id;}

int _selectedIndex;
    List<DoctorData> _options = [DoctorData(name:"doctor1",id:1),DoctorData(name:"doctor2",id:2), ];


Widget _buildChips() {
      List<Widget> chips = new List();
  
      for (int i = 0; i < _options.length; i++) {
        ChoiceChip choiceChip = ChoiceChip(
          selected: _selectedIndex == i,
          label: Text(_options[i].name, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
          avatar: FlutterLogo(),
          elevation: 10,
          pressElevation: 5,
          shadowColor: Colors.teal,
          backgroundColor: Colors.black54,
          selectedColor: Colors.blue,
          onSelected: (bool selected) {
            setState(() {
              if (selected) {
                _selectedIndex = i;
              }
            });
          },
        );
  
        chips.add(Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
          child: choiceChip
        ));
      }
  
      return ListView(
        // This next line does the trick.
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        children: chips,
      );
    }
```

you can display your choices as shown

```
Container(
                  height: 30,
                  child: _buildChips(),
                ),
```

you can alse check [multi_select_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/multi_select_flutter)